# adding a dynamic linearlayout to the current view android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am trying to add a linearlayout to a scrolview
this is my code
the code compiles, but it doesn't show me the new layout

this is the original layout (that i want to add to it)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 

android:layout_margin="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" 
     android:id="@+id/ViewHistoryImageLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/HistoryImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.76"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/upload" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/HistoryImage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TranslatedText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/translateImageButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the layout that i want to add several times:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/TranslationMenuLayout" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the java code for adding the new layout is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_history_image);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.translation_menu, null);
sv.addView(ll);
```

the code compiles fine, and the app is running but nothing happens
is there a problem with one of the .xml files?

tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use an inflater, 
change:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(R.layout.translation_menu);
```

with

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.translation_menu, null);
sv.addView(ll);
```

The `LayoutInflater` creates a `View` object from the corresponding XML file.

Comment: tnx! what is the variable context ?

Comment: You need a Context object in order to retrieve the call getSystemService. If you are inside an activity you can call directly getSystemService

Comment: oh yea, i used getApplicationContect()
but it doesn't work, the code compile and the app is running, but i don't see anything added to the layout
can it be something with the original layout?

Answer (score 1):

```
  LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.translation_menu, this)
```

This is the Correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LayoutInflator`.

`LayoutInflater` class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.

In other words, it takes as input an XML file and builds the View objects from it.

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );   
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(translation_menu, this);  
sv.addView(ll);
```